# How can I organize my functions to get something like class.draw.line() instead of class.drawLine

Tags: python

I often use functions that are nicely organized into calls such as `pygame.draw.circle`. I want to follow this structure in my class but do not know how do so. I tried using a nested class but it was limited to its own scope rather than its parent's, which was necessary for it to function.

1. How do I properly implement this feature?
2. Alternatively, is it a bad idea to attempt to mimic this except for certain scenarios? What should I be doing instead?

Comment: `pygame.draw` is a submodule, not a subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
| pygame/
|   __init__.py
|   draw/
|     __init__.py
|     circle.py
|     rectangle.py
```

Or, you could do it this way.

```
| pygame/
|   __init__.py
|   draw.py
```

> draw.py

```
def circle(*args):
    """ Draws a circle using *args """
    pass

def rectangle(*args):
    #  and so on
    pass
```

> your_project.py

```
from pygame.draw import circle, rectangle
circle(args)
rectangle(args)

#  or
from pygame import draw
draw.circle(args)
draw.rectangle(args)

#  or
import pygame
pygame.draw.circle(args)
```

You may want to read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages as you're making your final decisions.